# How to rewrite a batch of similar urls

Tags: .htaccess

I have a list of state urls like this, which are identical except the state name

/Wyoming_Red_Widgets
/Ohio_Red_Widgets

and want to redirect all to:

/red-widgets

Various patterns, although I am newer to Modrewrite / htaccess

Rewrite /([a-z]+)_Red_Widgets /red-widgets/

Nothing happens (no redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, but strictly speaking this probably is the closest answer to what you actually asked:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?.+Red_Widgets/?$ /red-widgets [END]
```

For this to work you need to make sure that dynamic configuration files (".htaccess" style files) are considered at all by the http server for this location (hint: `AllowOverride`) and they file is readable for the http server process.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).